# Does sonarqube exclusion property append or override other exclusion properties?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a large project that I am scanning with sonarqube using gradle. I have the following properties:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "*url goes here*"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "**/generated/**/*.java"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "**/uk/co/database/enums/*.java"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "**/policyTypesUtility/gen-src/**/*.java"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "**/ctest/**/*.java"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "**/uk/co/dataimport/integrationtest/src/main/java/**/*.java"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "**/uk/co/integration/test/reverseedi/src/main/java/**/*.java"
        etc...
    }
}
```

My question is, does each additional "sonar. exclusions" property override or append to the last? I have seen examples of one property with comma separated values. Can it be done either way or does it have to be a single property with multiple values?

Comment: "sonar.exclusions" is a key, and in your sample you are overriding it on each line. You have to set all exclusions only one time with comma separated values.

Comment: Superstar, thank you very much.